# how to hide my cakephp folder name in url

Tags: cakephp

am trying to hide my root folder name in url its like www.sitename.com/cakephp/index.html
here i want to hide that cakephp name from my url.help me please.
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have access to your server DocumentRoot then probably the easy way is just move the content of the cakephp to domain root. Another way is to move cakephp to private location in server, copy app/webroot to your domain root and modify paths in index.php in webroot. See http://book.cakephp.org/view/915/Advanced-Installation

Answer (score 0):

you can also change DocumentRoot of your web server to url/cakephp.